# What are the qualification documents required for releasing new app in Huawei App Gallery?

Tags: huawei-developers

What kind of documents should we upload for releasing the new app in Huawei App Gallery?

Comment: kindly check [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-releaseapkrpk-0000001106463276#section12761327123615).

Answer (score 0):

For both the individual as well as enterprise developer it is mandatory to provide copyright information if developers want to distribute the app in “Mainland China”. Publishing app to outside China it is not required to provide copyright information, but it is required to provide “Copyright Information(Disclaimer)” if  you want to distribute a common app to the Chinese mainland. Similarly It is required to provide “Copyright Information(Software copyright and Copyright disclaimer)” , if you want to distribute a game to the Chinese mainland

[image]

Please check below document link for selecting the category and copyright qualification :

App Categorization : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/app/50103

Copyright Qualification : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/app/30215